# WP RSS Feed output with all lowercase XML elements and attributes

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, apache, rss

We have had something go quirky with our Wordpress RSS Feeds. At first we noticed that the publication dates were being output as Dec 31, 1969. This of course is a side effect of passing an invalid date to PHP's Date().

While viewing the rendered XML for the feed I noticed that all of the XML elements and attributes are being forced to lowercase. For example, `<pubDate>` is showing up as `<pubdate>` and `<lastBuildDate>` is showing up as `<lastbuilddate>`, etc. All elements and attributes are being forced to all lowercase.

No other data is being effected from what I can see. Actual data content is being displayed with upper and lower case. Only the XML element names and their attributes are being effected.

This explains why we were seeing Dec 31, 1969 for the publication date... but I am no closer to a solution.

I don't think there is a setting in WP Dashboard that effects this. I doubt it has anything to do with the Apache HTTP server. More likely there is an XML related setting in for PHP, but this is just a guess.

Does anyone have a clue on what would cause XML element names/attributes to be forced to all lowercase?

Thanks.

Comment: that's one of the best practices, using lowercase character... what seems to be the problem regarding with the date? is the character case producing the problem? why or how did the character case affect the date?

Comment: I assume the client looks for `<pubDate>` but doesn't find it because something has changed it to `<pubdate>`. I can see in the server's .PHP code that these elements are specified with some uppercase. Yet by the time they are rendered on the client they become lowercase. XML is case sensitive (by default, at least) and the convention used is very common - first letter is lowercase, but the first letter of following words is uppercase. For example, myElementName or buildFrequency. So when the client RSS script looks for the date in `<pubDate>` it isn't found.